How can I write about a necromancer in my historical fiction novel without it being too slow, too fast, or too unrealistic?
Book details: it's a novel set in the 1700's American Revolution. The leader of the antagonists was killed and resurrected, and now he can summon an army of the dead.
My issues: Writing about him summoning his army without it being boring or too fast, writing about how he is able to summon soldiers, how many soldiers he could summon without it seeming a little to OP and "unrealistic" to unrealistic stuff.
I did a lot of research and it's set in the past, but the MC is a necromancer, and for some people historical novels are A: boring, B: slow paced, C: too fast, D: too much information.
Also I'm like 31 pages into it with about over 10,000 words.

That's not historical fiction. That's fantasy. To my knowledge there weren't any necromancers in history. Just so you submit it as the right genre.

You call your character "the leader of the antagonists", but in your comments it seems as if he is actually the protagonist. Could you clarify what role he has (protagonist or antagonist)? The answer will be quite different for each.

This question needs focus. Just write your story. Pacing and 'not being boring' will happen in your second draft.

If the necromancer is the antagonist (as your question says)
He can be all powerful and impossible to overcome. He will defeat the hero again and again.
Examples: Sauron in The Lord of the Rings or the Dark One in The Wheel of Time.
If the necromancer is the protagonist (or hero)
The hero is near powerless in the face of overwhelming odds. But he will never give up despite being defeated again and again. And as he picks himself up after every defeat, he slowly gains in strength, experience, and knowledge. And eventually he discovers the weakness of the antagonist and in a final confrontation, in which he almost loses his life, he manages to defeat the antagonist. But the antagonist is not killed, and in the shadows he will recover and eventually return with renewed and even greater strength in the sequel to try and rule the world again.
If your hero is a necromancer, his powers must be severly limited:

He can only call up one undead at a time.
The undead are slow and easy to "kill".
He can only call up undead when there is a full moon but the antagonist starts his attack three days before that.
The army of undead are held up by flowing water and there is a river or it starts to rain.
etc.

Example: Aragorn calling the Dead Men of Dunharrow in The Lord of the Rings.

Clarification, The Main Character is the antagonist aka the necromancer, and the book is centered around him. I've structured the book to where people can relate to the antagonist and some people might not like the protgonist group. Also, Strictly speaking, historical fiction is a fictional story with a historical setting, which tries to render that setting accurately, often with the aid of research. Fantasy, on the other hand, is entirely fictional, although most fantasy worlds draw inspiration from real human cultures and situations from the past.

@T.S By definition, the main character is the protagonist and his opponent is the antagonist. What you probably mean is that your main character, being a necromancer, is "bad" or "evil" in some way, that is, a villain. Also, by definition, historical fiction is fiction set in the real world depicting real events. Necromancers who can raise an army of the undead weren't real, though. You probably mean historical fantasy. It would help if you didn't use established terms against their common meaning.

To impose limitations:
Perhaps he has "the power", but not the knowledge, or experience -- he has to exercise this new "muscle" to make it strong enough.
So he was killed and resurrected; he knows from when he was alive this is supposed to give him the power to summon the undead.
But how and where, exactly?
He tries to summon a person, and fails. By trial and error, he finds he can summon a dead fly, it rises and attacks him and he kills it again. Then a dead bird -- same thing. He knows he's not doing it right, they should obey him, but these dead things keep trying to kill him.
There's nobody to ask, he's on his own, so he has to read, and experiment, and get stronger willed to be able to summon people. He learns a spell for "command voice", and that begins to control them. He manages to get a dead hawk to attack somebody he hates, and blind them before it is killed.
Plot his self-education.
In order for people to like your story, the hero (or anti-hero) needs to fail, repeatedly, or their victory becomes meaningless.
Read your favorite fiction, and notice how the hero gets set back, and tries again and gets set back, and tries again and fails even worse, but gets back up with their last ounce of willpower to try once again, and then they succeed.
As Stephen King says, you have to put your hero in the blender. Beat the crap out of him. Success without paying the price is not an entertaining story.

Despite the MC's unusual powers, the issues are actually very standard:

What's interesting about the situation?
What's stopping the MC from achieving their goals?

The situation is inherently interesting, but it's up to you to write it in such a way that it captures the reader. How do his powers work? What are his limitations? What are his motivations?
The next part is crucial - what is stopping the MC? If he just walks into a graveyard, waves his hand about and boom, undead army...well that's not very interesting. Does he have to learn by experimenting? Do his creations keep going wrong, attacking him or escaping? Are there graveyard guards? Does he have to break in somewhere to steal a book of magic? Is the priesthood trying to stop him?

Thanks Phil, I've not thought about that, limitations would make it very interesting. So, he was killed and resurrected with the eye of the apprentice which bestowes him the power to summon the undead, he wants revenge for his death and eventually the eye takes over him and now he's fighting the British, the Americans, the Hessians, and the protagonists. He wants to kill all humans basically. I guess at first his creations either suck or try to kill him, and he has to do certain things to hone his skills, I suppose I can figure that out. Thanks!
